# How to load a column of a matrix in R into a variable

Tags: r, variables, matrix

How do I load a column of a matrix in **R** as a variable? After I do that I want to access individual row elements in that variable created in a for loop, how do I access that? The matrix itself is only two dimensional.

Comment: Please read more introductory material and try further examples. This should be answered early in any basic text.

Answer (score 1):

use `[`

A sample matrix:

```
> mat=matrix(1:6, 2)
> mat
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    3    5
[2,]    2    4    6
```

Extract column 2:

```
> mat[,2]
[1] 3 4
```

What are you actually trying to do?  `for` is almost always the wrong approach.

Comment: if I say a <- mat[,2] does this save a as a vector?

Comment: the for loop is used to access the values from a specific row in a column then to do a comparison of those values with values in another vector